# My sites heading, which has 3 words, will not seperate. Feel like I've tried everything?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[Find the image here to understand what i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAv6c.png)

Been googling and fiddling around but I can't seem to seperate the words. The only separation I managed was using "justify-content: space-around".

Here's the HTML. And the CSS is below it

```css
body {
  background-color: #3269a8;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #282828;
  border-radius: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.logo:hover p {
  transition: 2000ms;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Top 3 Anime</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="header-container">
    <p class="logo-the logo">The</p> <p class="logo-big logo">Big</p> <p class="logo-three logo">Three</p>
  </div>

  <div class="top3">

    <div class="onepiece">One Piece</div>
    <div class="dragonball">Dragon Ball Z</div>
    <div class="naruto">Naruto</div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you want them to be separated to be exact?

Comment: you can use `word-spacing` property.

Comment: @LearningMathematics I'm just wanting a space or two between each word.

Comment: @KunalTanwar I've tried that, it doesn't change anything

Comment: just set `.logo-big { margin: 0 2rem; }` **or** `.logo-big { padding: 0 2rem; }` . change the value as you want or according the space you want.

Comment: In logo class you can add padding: 5px;, if that can help you.

Comment: @KunalTanwar You're a life saver!

Comment: Why dont you just try add a space in all your ```<p>``` elements respectively! It will be better than using css for it. Like after ```The``` add one space or try &nbps;

Comment: @HaydenBradford Anytime 

Answer (score 0):

You have used display:flex  in your header-container with justify-content:center; that will make the child p tags to be in a line without any space. if you just want little space around p tags you can add

```
.header-container p {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

and if you want to learn about flex and its properties you can learn from here [csstricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) , the have explained it beautifully.
I hope this will work for you

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can change the `<p>Your header</p>` to `<pre>Your Header</pre>`. Here `<pre>` keeps the format of the text including spaces. You can check this page: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Basically you just need to editted the following in your code:

```
    <pre class="logo-the logo">The </pre> <pre class="logo-big logo">Big </pre> <p class="logo-three logo">Three</p>
```

I added a space after "The" and "Big" so converted them to `<pre>`.

Comment: You do not need `<pre>` for that.